# User login to information on query string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a list of clubs that when a user clicks on one of the clubs it loads a query string. This then pulls the data relating to that club.

I need to set up a users so they can login and edit the information under that account. At the moment i am unsure of how i would set this up for a user.

The url that i have created looks like the following
clubpage.aspx?CategoryID=6

So a user that added under category id6 could log on to catergory 6 and edit the information.

Comment: Under what account? Club's account or User's own account?

Comment: That does not really say much. can you update and post more details. First of all...can you add question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at [Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eeyk640h.aspx) and [Authorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd.aspx), best place to start is MSDN.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eeyk640h.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd.aspx

Answer (score 0):

When loading the page you'll need to check which club you are looking at by checking the querystring:

```
int categoryID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Querystring["CategoryID"]);
```

You could also add another part to the querystring saying whether you are viewing the page or editing it:

```
clubpage.aspx?CategoryID=6&Mode=edit
```

and check for this too:

```
if (Convert.ToString(Request.Querystring["Mode"]).Equals("edit"))
{
...
```

If you put this in the Page_Load you might also want to check that the 'loading' logic is not in a postback (and doesn't run every time a button/control triggers a postback):

```
if (!Page.IsPostback)
{
    int catego...
```

and then within here you can load the editing fields and populate them with values from the database, showing a save or update button depending on some more logic.

Hope this is of some help.